# ModalRoute.withName never returns true in pushNamedAndRemoveUntil

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have been wrestling with this issue for a couple of days now and I haven't been able to find a solution, hence the post.
At one point in my app, I need to pop 2 routes from the navigator stack and push a new route. After researching the best way to do this, I have found that using `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` is the best way, as I can specify `ModalRoute.withName('/<route_name>')` and it will pop the routes until it reaches `/<route_name>` at which point it will stop and push the new route. This is the line I have been using `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/raceadmin_reporting', ModalRoute.withName('/raceadmin_page'));`.

My issue though is that it doesn't work for me. It doesn't seem to matter what I put in `/<route_name>`, `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` pops all the routes, which leads me to believe that `ModalRoute.withName` never returns true.

I have also tried `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/raceadmin_reporting', (route) => route == RaceAdminPage.route());` and it doesn't work either.

When I look at the debugger, this is what I see:
[App Navigator Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iipM2.png)

The route I am trying to pop until is the `RaceAdmin` page, which is clearly in the stack. In the definition of that class, I added the line `static const routeName = '/raceadmin_page';` which is what I call in `ModalRoute.withName('/raceadmin_name')` and it doesn't work.

My routes are defined in the `routes.dart` file as per below:

```
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RailMeatApp());
      case '/raceadmin_page':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const RaceAdminPage());
      case '/raceadmin_pendinglist':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PendingResultsList());
      case '/raceadmin_pendingresults':
        final args = settings.arguments as Map<String?, String?>;
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => PendingResultsPage(
                  raceId: args['raceId'] as String,
                ));
      case '/raceadmin_reporting':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RaceAdminReporting());
      default:
        return _errorRoute();
    }
  }
```

And my `MaterialApp` is defined as per below:

```
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
      home: _railmeatHome(),
      onGenerateRoute: RailmeatRoutes.generateRoute,
    );
  }
```

In the Flutter debugger, I can look at the `MaterialApp` widget and I can see in its state that the navigator has 4 entries in its `_history` property as shown below:
[MaterialApp Widget Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IULEZ.png)

If I click on any of the entries in the `_history`, I see the the same info as below:
[Route property in _history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wa4A.png)

As you can see, the `name` property under `_settings` is `null`, which, in my mind, would explain why `ModalRoute.withName` can't find the right route, but I am not sure that my thinking is accurate.

What should I do differently to make `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` work?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Bertrand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```dart
Navigator.of(context)
    .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/routename', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);

Or

Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/root'));
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but this won't work as it will pop all the routes on the stack, instead of pop'ing the routes up to a certain route.

Comment: The `popUntil` doesn't work either. I tried `Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/raceadmin_page')` and it pop'ed all the pages until the root.